# Datasnapshot Loop not getting executed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a program for location tracking, I am using Firebase to make it work, so in doing so I used Datasnapshot i.e `addValueEventListener` and override the method `onDataChange` and applied a loop i.e for (`DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()`) but the content of this loop is not getting executed/traversed. Code attached. Please help.

```
DatabaseReference locations;
Double lat, lng;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private String email;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_tracking);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    locations = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Locations");

    if(getIntent() != null){
        email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
        lat = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lat", 0);
        lng = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lng", 0);
    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
       // Toast.makeText(this, " location for this user ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        loadLocationForThisUser(email);


    }

}

private void loadLocationForThisUser(String email) {
    Query user_location = locations.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);

    user_location.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        //locations.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(MapTracking.this, "ondatachange", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Toast.makeText(MapTracking.this, "ondatachange1223", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Tracking tracking = postSnapshot.getValue(Tracking.class);
                Toast.makeText(MapTracking.this, tracking.getLat() + " friend's location " + tracking.getLng(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                LatLng friendlocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(tracking.getLat()),
                        Double.parseDouble(tracking.getLng()));

                Location currentuser = new Location("");
                currentuser.setLatitude(lat);
                currentuser.setLongitude(lng);

                Location friend = new Location("");
                friend.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(tracking.getLat()));
                friend.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(tracking.getLng()));

                Toast.makeText(MapTracking.this, tracking.getLat() + " friend's location " + tracking.getLng(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mMap.clear();

                distance(currentuser, friend);

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(friendlocation)
                        .title(tracking.getEmail())
                        .snippet("Distance" + new DecimalFormat("#.#").format((currentuser.distanceTo(friend)) / 1000) + " km ")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 12.0f));
                }

            LatLng current = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                //Toast.makeText(MapTracking.this, current.latitude + " current location " + current.longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(current).title(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**Database structure**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you share your database structure and as an example show what value you are passing to your `loadLocationForThisUser()` method?

Comment: map.putExtra("email", user.getEmail());    The value passed in loadLocationForThisUser() is the other user's email id whose location has to be shown on the map. And the database structure is shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this could be due to a typo. Your simplified database structure is as follows:

```
- Location
    - pushId
        - email: "someone@example.com"
        - lat: "25.0"
        - lon: "15.0"
        - uid: userId
```

But you are attaching a `ValueEventListener` to the `Locations` node instead, which doesn't exist, so no data is ever retrieved from the database:

```
locations = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Locations");
```

If you change this to point to the "Location" node instead, your `onDataChange()` method should work:

```
locations = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Location");
Query user_location = locations.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
```

Comment: Ohh, this is embarrassing. Sorry, for the trouble. Thanks.

Comment: @KapilMulchandani It's OK, this happens to all of us!